polars getting a StringCacheMismatchError even after using stringcache context manager
Using polars throughout
I want to use replace to kind of like labelencode my categorical columns. The problem is that my dataframe is made by concatenating other dataframes
I can do the following:
df1 = pl.DataFrame(
    {'a':[1,2],
     'b':['a','b']}, 
    schema = {'a':pl.Float32, 'b': pl.Categorical})
cats = df1['b'].cat.get_categories().to_list()
df1 = df1.with_columns(
    pl.col('b').replace(cats, range(len(cats)), return_dtype = pl.Int32)
    )
print(df1)

output:
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ f32 ┆ i32 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ 0   │
│ 2.0 ┆ 1   │

But the following fails:
with pl.StringCache():
    df1 = pl.DataFrame(
        {'a':[1,2],
         'b':['a','b']}, 
        schema = {'a':pl.Float32, 'b': pl.Categorical})
    df2 = pl.DataFrame(
        {'c':[3,4], 'b':['a','c']}, 
        schema = {'c': pl.Int32, 'b': pl.Categorical})
df = pl.concat([df1, df2], how = 'diagonal')
print(df)
output:
shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬──────┐
│ a    ┆ b   ┆ c    │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ f32  ┆ cat ┆ i32  │
╞══════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 1.0  ┆ a   ┆ null │
│ 2.0  ┆ b   ┆ null │
│ null ┆ a   ┆ 3    │
│ null ┆ c   ┆ 4    │
└──────┴─────┴──────┘

cats = df['b'].cat.get_categories().to_list()
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.col('b')
    .replace(cats, range(len(cats)), return_dtype = pl.Int32))
print(df)

output:
StringCacheMismatchError: cannot compare categoricals coming from different sources, 
consider setting a global StringCache.




How can I replace the categories with an integer using replace in case my dataframe is formed by concatenating several other dataframes?

It is unclear to me if your example is supposed to work or not - or if this is a problem with .replace()
If everything is performed inside the with block - there is no error.
with pl.StringCache():
    df1 = pl.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'b':['a','b']}, schema = {'a':pl.datatypes.Float32, 'b': pl.datatypes.Categorical})
    df2 = pl.DataFrame({'c':[3,4], 'b':['a','c']}, schema = {'c': pl.datatypes.Int32, 'b': pl.datatypes.Categorical})
   
    df = pl.concat([df1, df2], how = 'diagonal')
    cats = df['b'].cat.get_categories().to_list()
    
    df = df.with_columns(pl.col('b').replace(cats, range(len(cats)), return_dtype = pl.datatypes.Int32))

shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬──────┐
│ a    ┆ b   ┆ c    │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ f32  ┆ i32 ┆ i32  │
╞══════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 1.0  ┆ 0   ┆ null │
│ 2.0  ┆ 1   ┆ null │
│ null ┆ 0   ┆ 3    │
│ null ┆ 2   ┆ 4    │
└──────┴─────┴──────┘

Categoricals in Polars are already backed by a numerical type. (UInt32)
You can use .to_physical() to access it.
df.with_columns(pl.col("b").to_physical())

shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬──────┐
│ a    ┆ b   ┆ c    │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ f32  ┆ u32 ┆ i32  │
╞══════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 1.0  ┆ 0   ┆ null │
│ 2.0  ┆ 1   ┆ null │
│ null ┆ 0   ┆ 3    │
│ null ┆ 2   ┆ 4    │
└──────┴─────┴──────┘


wow.. thanks. This reduces the runtime of my code significantly as well. Can you also shed some light on the earlier error I'm facing? Or, shall I ask another question for that?

Yeah, it's not entirely clear to me if it is a "bug" with .replace or not. If you put  all the code inside the with block - it works, right?

yes it works that way

You could try using Enums to avoid StringCache issues. The trade off is that you must predefine them with their valid values but it means you are able to do that manually instead of relying on keeping the StringCache open.
So you could do:
df1 = pl.DataFrame(
    {'a':[1,2],
        'b':['a','b']}, 
    schema = {'a':pl.Float32, 'b': pl.Categorical})
df2 = pl.DataFrame(
    {'c':[3,4], 'b':['a','c']}, 
    schema = {'c': pl.Int32, 'b': pl.Categorical})
super_b_enum=pl.Enum(
    pl.concat([
        df1['b'].cat.get_categories(), 
        df2['b'].cat.get_categories()
        ])
    .unique()
    .sort() # The physical backing will match the order
    )
df=pl.concat([
    df1.with_columns(pl.col('b').cast(super_b_enum)),
    df2.with_columns(pl.col('b').cast(super_b_enum))
], how='diagonal')
print(df.with_columns(i=pl.col('b').to_physical()))
shape: (4, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬─────┐
│ a    ┆ b    ┆ c    ┆ i   │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ f32  ┆ enum ┆ i32  ┆ u32 │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 1.0  ┆ a    ┆ null ┆ 0   │
│ 2.0  ┆ b    ┆ null ┆ 1   │
│ null ┆ a    ┆ 3    ┆ 0   │
│ null ┆ c    ┆ 4    ┆ 2   │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴─────┘

